# Using TypeScript "paths" at two different directory levels in a monorepo

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I have a TypeScript monorepo that is structured something like this:

```
├── tsconfig.base.json
└── packages
   ├── app
   │  ├── src/
   │  └── tsconfig.json
   └── components
      └── tsconfig.json
```

The child `tsconfig.json` files all extend from the base `tsconfig.base.json` file located at the root of the monorepo. But only the base defines the `paths` and the `baseUrl`.

Now, here's the catch. I would like to do the following things at the same time:

1. Put `packages/components` into `paths`.
2. Alias all of the files in the `src` directory of `app` as `~` so that I don't have to use relative paths in the `app` files.

I tried to define the paths like this:

```json
"paths": [
  "@componens": ["./packages/components"],
  "~/*": ["./packages/app/src/*"],
```

But `~` didn't work in my imports.

Is this doable at all? I tried to define the `~` path in the app's `tsconfig.json`, but then the `@component` path didn't work anymore. I also tried to play a bit with [`rootDirs`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#rootDirs), but I didn't get anywhere.